How can i move the charts on a panel in C# Forms using Livecharts extension?
How can i move the charts on a panel in C# Forms using Livecharts extension?
I'm using LiveCharts, LiveCharts.Wpf and LiveCharts.WinForms and i'm trying too move the chart on a panel also i've implemented a event on Shift+Click too delete the chart, but still it doesn't work. The code for creating the chart looks like this:
private void LineChart(string sensorName)
{
    Panel currentPanel = MainDashboard.Controls.OfType<Panel>().FirstOrDefault(panel => panel.Visible);

    if (currentPanel != null)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> sensorData = server.GetSenzorData();
        if (sensorData.ContainsKey(sensorName))
        {
            LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart chart = new LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart
            {
                Size = new Size(200, 200),
                Name = $"{sensorName}_Chart",
                Location = new Point(333, 353),
               
                
                
            };

            LiveCharts.Wpf.LineSeries lineSeries = new LiveCharts.Wpf.LineSeries
            {
                Title = sensorName,
                Values = new LiveCharts.ChartValues<double>(sensorData[sensorName].Select(double.Parse).ToList()),
                PointGeometry = null
            };

            chart.Series = new LiveCharts.SeriesCollection { lineSeries };

            chart.AxisX.Add(new LiveCharts.Wpf.Axis
            {
                Title = "Time",
                Labels = sensorData[sensorName].Select((s, index) => index.ToString()).ToArray()
            });

            chart.AxisY.Add(new LiveCharts.Wpf.Axis
            {
                Title = "Value"
            });

            chart.MouseDown += Chart_MouseDown;
            chart.MouseMove += Chart_MouseMove;
            chart.MouseUp += Chart_MouseUp;
            chart.MouseClick += Chart_MouseClick;
           
            var existingChart = currentPanel.Controls.OfType<LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingChart != null)
            {
                currentPanel.Controls.Remove(existingChart);
            }

            currentPanel.Controls.Add(chart);
        }
    }
}

The code for moving looks like this:
 private void Chart_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     isDraggingChart = true;
     startPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
     Console.WriteLine("Se Incearca Mutarea");
 }

 private void Chart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (isDragging)
     {
         LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart chart = sender as LiveCharts.WinForms.PieChart;
         chart.Location = new Point(chart.Location.X + e.X - startPoint.X, chart.Location.Y + e.Y - startPoint.Y);
     }
 }

 private void Chart_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     isDraggingChart = false;
 }

The code for deleting looks like this:
 private void Chart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift))
     {
         LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart chart = sender as LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart;
         Panel parentPanel = chart.Parent as Panel;
         if (parentPanel != null)
         {
             parentPanel.Controls.Remove(chart);
         }
     }
 }

I think it’s due to the chart settings because when I hold the click over it, it shows the value, and I don't think the chart is considered an element of the form even though it is added there.

With my code when i press click too move the chart instead of moving it, it shows the value of the chart. I think that's the problem it overwrite my command.
I need to be able too move the chart when i hold click on it and delete it when i shift-click!
How can i fix the code, so i can move the charts in the panel and delete them with Shift+Click.
